# Using localization in asp.net core application in class called from controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization

I have an asp.net core application and Im trying to implement localization throughout. I have no issues using localization in the controller or the view but my problem is I have a data store class that I call from my controller that does all database calls, in this class I create error messages if something fails but I want to make sure these error messages are localized. Is there a way to use localization in classes that arent the actual controller?

In my controller Im using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization and IStringLocalizer to localize strings.

Comment: I would recommend not passing text and end user will see out from the code anywhere. It's better to know that all content the user will see is only held in views (or in resources referenced by the view). Otherwise you're referencing localisable strings all over the place. Pass a value back to the view that tells it to show or hide an error.

Comment: BTW - are you using Razor?

Comment: @SteveJ I am using Razor. And Im not spitting out the error message from the conrtoller, my view model has a list of error messages and then the view model will display those. Im just creating the error messages in the data store as they occur